# Pass a form value to a link

Tags: php, forms, post

I have searched the site for an answer but nothing I tried is working. I am trying to create a simple, 1 field form for the value "billid" to pass to the end of a URL, but am having no luck. The URL opens in a popup window, which works, but I can't get the field value to populate. Here is my code:

```
<?php
        if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $billid = $_POST['bid1'];
    ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onSubmit="centeredPopup('/plugins/community/statement/statement/statement.php?userid=<?php echo $memid; ?>&billingid=<?php echo $billid; ?>','myWindow','900','750','yes');return false" >
<input type="text" name="bid1">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form> <?php }  ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why using <?php }  ?> at the end ?

Comment: @AvinashBabu he is closing his if condition

Comment: You say you want the value at the end of the url correct? Shouldn't you just use a "get" method instead of "post"? The form redirects before the php on that page is ran. Unless I am mistaken.

Comment: @SpencerMay: Add your comment as an answer

Comment: how do you get $_POST['bid1'] if condtion is if(!isset($_POST['submit']))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the input directly in js using `this.inputname.value`:

```
<form method="post" action="" onSubmit="showPopup(this.bid1.value);return false" >
    <input type="text" name="bid1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="application/javascript">
    function showPopup(billingId){
        centeredPopup(
            '/plugins/community/statement/statement/statement.php?userid=<?php echo $memid; ?>&billingid=' + billingId,
            'myWindow','900','750','yes'
        )
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a php call from this value and use it instead of the + this.bid1.value?

Comment: @CharlieTrig No, php has finished running by time the page is displayed. Why would you like to do that? There is probably a solution

Comment: Once you understand that PHP is server side, and Javascript is client side, you will know the answer to your question :) (Hint: no)

Comment: What I was trying to do next was to make userid=<?php echo $memid; ?> into the same as the billingid. The system uses the same ID for billing and userid, so it will 'pull' the name of the member and populate it on the popup page.

Comment: @CharlieTrig well the popup page is accepting parameters through the url, so could you just change the parameter to use the billingID javascript variable, eg `'/plugins/community/statement/statement/statement.php?userid=' + billingId + '&billingid=' + billingId`

Comment: @CharlieTrig That said, if both id's are the same, why do you need to pass them both? I think i am confused

Comment: The URL uses the userid and the billingid to pull data from a MySQL DB (userid) and an XML data file (billingid). In this system, the userID and the billing ID are the same, for other references. By referencing the userid in the URL, it 'pulls' the user name and other data from the DB.

Comment: This code does not work, it is not formatted right: onSubmit="centeredPopup('/plugins/community/statement/statement/statement.php?userid=(this.bid1.value)&billingid=' + this.bid1.value,'myWindow','900','750','yes');return false"

Comment: Got it to work with: onSubmit="centeredPopup('/plugins/community/statement/statement/statement.php?userid=' + this.bid1.value + '&billingid=' + this.bid1.value,'myWindow','900','750','yes');return false">

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not actually submiting the form, you can't pass that information with PHP. You should grab the user entered information with javascript. Here is some code that should work:

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
      onSubmit="centeredPopup('/plugins/community/statement/statement/statement.php?userid=<?php echo $memid; ?>&billingid=' + document.getElementById('bid1').value,'myWindow','900','750','yes');return false">
    <input type="text" name="bid1" id="bid1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: This one didn't work, stopped my popup from working.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use php for this. You can use only JavaScript to grab the input.
You can do:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onSubmit="centeredPopup('/plugins/community/statement/statement/statement.php?userid=yourid&billingid=' + this.bid1.value, 'myWindow', '900', '750', 'yes'); return false" >
    <input type="text" name="bid1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly, thanks!! Is there a way to change the '+ this.bid1.value' to a php call so I can use it elsewhere? Something like $billid = + this.bid1.value; ?

Comment: @CharlieTrig why did you switch your accepted answer to this one?

Comment: I refreshed the page and the area jumped due to other answers, sorry! Still getting used to StackOverflow!